# Git submodule pull changes when branch is changed in .gitmodules

Tags: git

I have a .gitmodules with the following content

```
[submodule "ext/coffee"]
    path = ext/coffee
    url = http://bb.lan/scm/src/coffee.git
    branch = v1.0.2
```

When I switch my .gitmodule to

```
[submodule "ext/coffee"]
path = ext/coffee
url = http://bb.lan/scm/src/coffee.git
branch = v1.0.1
```

What do I need to do to have git re-pull submodule with v1.0.1?

The

> branch=v1.0.1

and

> v.1.0.2

are tags on two different branches in the repo. It appears that when I'm cloning the repo the right tag gets pulled, but not when doing pulls and updates.

Comment: `git submodule sync && git submodule update ext/coffee`

Comment: I tried that but the branch/tag of the submodule remains the same v1.0.0.

Comment: For whatever reasons .git/config isn't updating with .gitmodules content of the branch property. Should it be updating there ?

Comment: `git submodule sync` should copy changes to`.git/config`.